# How to get the last string in line, and insert it to array?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, line

I have the following file:

```
1 0x000 1555106270.959849 0x02b
0 0x3ff 1555106270.967866 0x02c
0 0x3fe 1555106270.975882 0x02d
0 0x3fd 1555106270.983898 0x02e
0 0x3fc 1555106270.991915 0x02f
0 0x3fb 1555106270.999931 0x000
0 0x3fa 1555106271.007947 0x001
0 0x3f9 1555106271.015964 0x002
0 0x3f8 1555106271.023980 0x003
0 0x3f7 1555106271.031997 0x004
0 0x3f6 1555106271.040013 0x005
0 0x3f5 1555106271.048029 0x006
```

(it might have more lines).

I want to get the last string in each line, and insert it to array.

I try the following:

```
arr_int = []
i = 0
result_file = open('result.txt', 'r')
for line in result_file:
    line.split()
    arr_int[i] = int(line.split()[-1])
    ++i
print (arr_int[2])
```

I got the following error:

```
arr_int[i] = int(line.split()[-1])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the problem, but `++i` does not increment `i`

Comment: There's an empty line somewhere, maybe at the end?

Comment: @Elliot Roberts- so what does?

Comment: @Klaus D - there isn't.

Comment: `i += 1` but using variables like this is usually considered un-pythonic. I'd do `for i, line in enumerate(result_file)`

Comment: One line: `with open('result.txt', 'r') as f: arr_int = [int(line.split()[-1], 16) for line in f]`.  Note that you want `int("0x02b", 16)` because `int("0x02b")` will raise `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`.  `line.split()[-1]` could be slightly more efficient as `line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]` because splitting only once from the right gives you exactly the string you need.

Comment: @KlausD.:  I think you're assuming an empty line because the `IndexError`, but the `IndexError` is actually caused by the OP trying to assign to an index on an empty array (`arr_int = []`  and then later `arr_int[i] = ...`).

Answer (score 4):

as this is python, there's no `++i` and additionally, python doesn't allow array assignment to arbitrary non-existent indices (unlike javascript).

you need to do 2 things. first, use `append`. secondly, you need to specify the base for the int (as it's not base 10):

```
arr_int.append(int(line.split()[-1], 16))
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr_int` is defined as an empty array, so you can't index into it. Use `append` instead:

```
arr_int.append(int(line.split()[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need index access during assignments to list. Lists in python are not arrays as you know them from C or C++:

```
last_words = []

with open('result.txt', 'r') as result_file:
    for line in result_file:
        last_words.append(int(line.split()[-1]), 16)

print(last_words[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may hit a empty row. Try to filter out the empty row before access the element.

```
with open('result.txt', 'r') as result_file:
  for line in result_file:
    if line.split():
      arr_int.append(int(line.split()[-1]))
```

Comment: I think you're assuming an empty line because the `IndexError`, but the `IndexError` is actually caused by the OP trying to assign to an index on an empty array (`arr_int = []`  and then later `arr_int[i] = ...`).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you are right. i did not think about it, but my answer also resolved that part

Answer (score 0):

Python does not allow in-place assignment. You can try this instead:

```
final_data = [i.strip('\n').split()[-1] for i in open('file.txt')]
```